# How to hide virtual keyboard in android

Tags: android

i used this code

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(EditView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

this code works fine in a class which extends Activity

but i need to hide virtual keyboard in a class which extends LinearLayout.

Comment: Why would you want to hide the soft keyboard?

Comment: i found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard